# How to disable or hide browser (IE) refresh button by javascript

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, button, refresh, hide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we disable browser's buttons(back/forward/refresh) by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078650/can-we-disable-browsers-buttonsback-forward-refresh-by-javascript)

Currently working on a project which has built by some another person & i'm on way of fixing some wired things. For this i want to "disable or hide the browser button(specifically of IE)".

So, i want to know is their any way to do this. I searched a lot about this over net but didn't get any perfect answer.

Comment: When in doubt ask the same question twice?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078650/can-we-disable-browsers-buttonsback-forward-refresh-by-javascript