# Restrict user to refresh and back,forward in any browser

Tags: jquery, html, browser

I am working on an evaluation system, In which candidate attempt for an exam. So the page where a question and its choices are get rendered is a page with `iframe` , In that questions are get the render. The page which holds `iframe` contains `JavaScript` timer.

So when questions get render on the browser to restrict refresh I have written `F5` and `ctrl+F5` blocking code so candidate can't refresh using keyboard shortcuts but in a browser window, one can still use refresh button or back button. Is there any way to disable this? I know playing with browser functionality is not good practice, So is there any way to get out of this.

Comment: You can visit this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078650/can-we-disable-browsers-buttonsback-forward-refresh-by-javascript

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya any alternative...

Comment: No,i don't have any alternative.Sorry :)

Comment: How are you going to prevent the user from using a developer toolbar/debugger to circumvent your scripts, or maybe to disable javascript at all?

Comment: This won't work. For example any savvy student could throw together a bookmarklet that kills the timer by issuing a client-side JS command to cancel the timeout/interval. Pass it out to their friends and no one needs to worry about time limits anymore. You need to implement actual server-side code for this or accept that it's easily attacked and badly coded.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini can I user <noscript> tag to handle client-side JS command to cancel the timeout/interval. or disabling JavaScript.

Comment: @Amogh No. As long as the thing you're trying to enforce on the user is done in Javascript and not on the server, the user can thwart/trick/manipulate whatever they want.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Thanks for your valuable guidelines...on internet there are son many frameworks for online tests they also have timer.. how they implemented that timer is that in JavaScript or any think else...

Comment: Either they enforce that same timer on the server side, or they're easily attacked and rendered useless.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini as this project is developed in Spring MVC...so we are trying to implement java applet for the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

on `document.ready` I added this line..

`window.history.forward(-1)`

Comment: it not working in chrome browser. if can possible then provide demo (jsfiddle)

Answer (score 10):

Try this to disable back button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.history.forward();
      function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
    </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="noBack();"
     onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

Or we can remove these from the tool bar

```
window.open ("URL",
"mywindow","status=1,toolbar=0");
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this for restrict back button in all latest browser.

```
history.pushState({ page: 1 }, "Title 1", "#no-back");
window.onhashchange = function (event) {
  window.location.hash = "no-back";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

Comment: this will prevent browsers  from back

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.  Disable caching if you don't want people seeing old pages by going "back", but all they're seeing is things they've just seen anyway so it doesn't make a difference.  people having been asking for 20 years how to disable the back button and so far I never seen a site where back button is disables.

But yes here one trick

Thanks

```
window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button";//again because google chrome don't insert first hash into history
window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
```

Comment: Oh my that feels so devious.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...:-

```
window.open ("http://viralpatel.net/blogs/",
"mywindow","status=1,toolbar=0");
```

This opens a window without toolbar...
NO toolbar no buttons..  :D

Comment: @sankalp Mishra  if we i use the way you said,then in mozilla it asks for the permission to open for a new pop window.If permitted then only its opening

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault(); };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsPageRefresh = false;

//this section of code checks if the page postback is due to genuine submit by user or by pressing "refresh"

if (!IsPostBack)  
{
    ViewState["ViewStateId"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Session["SessionId"] = ViewState["ViewStateId"].ToString();
}
else
{
    if (ViewState["ViewStateId"].ToString() != Session["SessionId"].ToString())
    {
        IsPageRefresh = true;
    }
    Session["SessionId"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ViewState["ViewStateId"] = Session["SessionId"].ToString();
}
```