# Restrict browser refresh, f5, browser back like banking sites through javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Some of you aware of the F5, browser refresh/back button functionality in some banking web sites...like that is there any possible cross-browser way to control browser functionality with javascript/jquery

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078650/can-we-disable-browsers-buttonsback-forward-refresh-by-javascript

Comment: I'm aware that every site - including banking websites - can be refreshed.

Answer (score 3):

(1) No. There no possible cross-browser way to control browser functionality with javascript/jquery.

(2) Banking sites do not restrict or control the browser functionality. They only ask users to desist. At most they attempt to detect some actions and then show errors. But, they don't try to control the browser.

(3) This is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day some banking sites would spawn a new window in javascript without any browser chrome. This doesn't disable refreshes and page navigation, but it makes it a little less likely that novice users will initiate them.

I believe most banking sites these days just disable the page caching and show an error message telling you not to refresh the page if you reload of press back, in combination with some server side tracking of your navigation.

Comment: Yes Matthew. In fact, I have seen some sites blocking right-click as well. I don't know what purpose that served, but inappropriate nevertheless.

Comment: They are control freaks!